# How to get IP address from username

Tags: windows-server-2003, user-accounts

In a Windows Server 2003 network with domain, is it possible to obtain the IP address or PC name only with username? Using Windows cmd.exe commands from any client on the network.

Comment: Its not clear what you want to do other than get an IP address, can you detail your question more please.

Comment: Are you a domain administrator? if no then the answer is no, if yes you need MUCH more training and until you get that let someone else do your job.

Comment: @Chopper3  That seems like a particularly cruel thing to force on this "someone else" you make mention of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible as asked, primarily because user-accounts/usernames do not have IP addresses or PCs.

***Users***, on the other hand, often have have PCs, which may be assigned IP addresses, and if that's what you're trying to track, it is possible to track down the IP address of the PC that a given username logs into or accesses over the network.

However, this involves reading logs (start on the Domain Controller(s)), rather than expecting an arbitrary instance of `cmd.exe` on an arbitrary computer to automagically know what networked resources an arbitrary username is being used to authenticate against.

Comment: Nice answer. I agree with Chopper3's remark as well. I've been training junior admins lately... At least, they claim to be admins...

Comment: Just to defend myself, I'm not a network admin, just an IT worker trying to access with remote desktop to a particular PC but didn't know its IP or name. Users at my office can't help me too much giving me that information.

Comment: @user316687 Your users can't 'Start' -> 'Run...' -> `cmd` -> `ipconfig /all`?

Comment: Using PsLoggedOn enables me to get username, running: " psloggedon \\pcname "     Wouldn't be any tool to do exactly the opposite? I mean, giving username and getting PC name.

Comment: No, because doing "psloggedon \\pcname" instructs the psloggedon command to go to the specific PC specified by "\\pcname" and query for the username that is currently logged into it. A tool that did something like "psloggedon username" would have to scan the whole network since that user could be logged into any PC on the network.  If your users have dedicated workstations, then you should have some way (database, spreadsheet, etc) of tracking the PC that was assigned to them and go off that to figure out which PC they are likely using.

Comment: @user316687 In addition to what August said above, get your SA(s)/network admin(s) to grant you access to the Domain Controller's security event logs, from which you can search for a given username to see what IP it's authing to the DCs from.  You don't even need to log onto the DCs, you can use the Event Viewer on your PC to target a remote system's event logs.  May motivate them to mention that this would enable you to handle more "user shit" without their help, and would result in you bothering them for logged information less.

Comment: Thanks to HopelessN00b and August. I clearly understand now.